# Jira create issue. Inserting text inline from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to programmatically create a table in Jira for a migration tool I'm writing. Inside the description, there's a table that holds all of the source and destination information. However, I cannot get the table to populate.
My call data is as follows.

```
    const data={
    fields:{
        project:{
            key: config.jira.project
        },
        summary:"Migration Tool - Migrating repositories",
        description: `Migating repositories\n
            Validated Bitbucket repositories:\n
            ||ID||Bitbucket Key||Bitbucket repo slug||Github Organization||Github repo name||
            ${input.validated.forEach(item => {
                return (`|${item.id}|${item.bitbucket.projectKey}|${item.bitbucket.repositoryName}|${item.github.org}|${item.github.repositoryName}|\n`)
                // console.log(validatedTable(item))
                // return(validatedTable(item))
            })}
            
            Invalid Bitbucket repositories:\n`,
        issuetype:{
            name:"Task"
        },
        customfield_10005: config.jira.epic
    }
}
```

At the moment, it's returning undefined.  How do I get the text too return and populate the table?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't like me trying to build the text string up from inside the string, as above.

My fix was to build the strings into variables and then call the variable.

```
var validatedString = ""
var invalidatedString = ""
for (const item of input.validated) {
    validatedString = validatedString + `|${item.id}|${item.bitbucket.projectKey}|${item.bitbucket.repositoryName}|${item.github.org}|${item.github.repositoryName}|\n`
}
for (const item of input.invalidated) {
    invalidatedString = invalidatedString + `|${item.id}|${item.bitbucket.projectKey}|${item.bitbucket.repositoryName}|${item.github.org}|${item.github.repositoryName}|${item.error.message}\n`
}
const data={
    fields:{
        project:{
            key: config.jira.project
        },
        summary:"Migration Tool - Migrating repositories",
        description: `Migating repositories\n
            Validated Bitbucket repositories:\n
            ||ID||Bitbucket Key||Bitbucket repo slug||Github Organization||Github repo name||
            ${validatedString}\n
            Invalid Bitbucket repositories:\n
            ||ID||Bitbucket Key||Bitbucket repo slug||Github Organization||Github repo name||Error||
            ${invalidatedString}`,
        issuetype:{
            name:"Task"
        },
        customfield_10005: config.jira.epic
    }
}
```

I had to declare the variables with the `=""` at the end, otherwise the first part of the string always had `undefined`